# Charging IC problem: charging restarts every 12 hours without load on battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, load

I'm using the [MCP73837](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/268/MCHP_S_A0001275632_1-2520955.pdf) charger IC.

After charging is finished the IC goes into charging mode again every 12 hours for 6 hours, even though the battery is connected all that time with no load.

According to the data sheet, there is no time in a component of the "MCP73837T-FCI/UN" type, so what is the reason for this behavior, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: For application support you should be contacting Microchip esp since you seem to be doing commercial development. What have you done to rule out some obvious causes? Does the mains blip every 12 hours?  Have you tried a different sized battery? Putting a load on the battery? Try to determine if the time is independent of the battery or its voltage?  Try things to get some evidence on the problem. There could be a million reasons specific to your setup that might cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet (see 4.8) the IC has an automatic recharge feature that kicks in when the battery voltage drops to about 97% of V<sub>BAT(high)</sub> (see 1.0). This percentage can vary across ICs and be as high as 99% at normal ambient temperatures, so just a 1% drop.

It could well be that it is this automatic recharging you are seeing when after about 12 hours the battery voltage has dropped a bit because of self-discharging and/or the IC's standby power consumption or reverse output leakage current.

Monitoring the battery voltage can tell you if this is, or could be, the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me where it is mentioned 97% ? I couldn't find it.

Comment: It's the Typical Value in the table on page 5 of the datasheet under "Automatic Recharge" for normal ambient temperatures.

Comment: Oh, can you advise me on what to test to debug the reasons for this issue?

Comment: If what I wrote is indeed the case, it's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

According to data sheet, the chip marked  with "FC" does have a 6 hour safety timer.

So if the battery does not charge in 6 hours, the charging stops and the chip goes into timer fault mode.

Why the charging starts again is unknown, but all the conditions which make the chip go out of timer fault are listed in the data sheet, so you only need to figure out which of the conditions happen every 12 hours and why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me check and get back.

Comment: Does it happen because of self-discharging and/or the IC's standby power consumption or reverse output leakage current, as mentioned by the previous answer by @ocrdu.

Comment: I cannot know without debugging and measuring it if that is the reason, or something else. You have the device so you are able to measure and debug it and find out what triggers the recharge; does the battery not fully charge in 6h, or does it recharge because voltage drops too low.

Comment: Oh, can you provide a direction on what to check?

Comment: "but all the conditions which make the chip go out of timer fault is listed in the data sheet, so you only need to figure out which of the conditions happen every 12 hours and why." - Could you tell me where are the conditions mentioned in the datasheet?